# Entropy of a Continuous and Uniform Random Variable

Tags: uniform-distribution, continuous-data, entropy

The distribution of a uniform r.v. X is given as follows:

[image]

The entropy is therefore:

[image]

This means that as $∆$ approaches infinity, so does the entropy.
This also means that as $∆$ approaches 0, the entropy approaches negative infinity.

A couple questions about the interpretation of this entropy:

1. Does infinite entropy mean that we need infinite information to determine/represent the random variable?
2. What does it mean to have negative entropy? What does an entropy of negative infinity mean? I thought that an entropy of zero meant that we need no information to determine/represent a distribution. Therefore, negative entropy does not make sense to me.

Comment: Which distribution(s) do you suppose "need no information" for their representation??

Comment: @whuber I was thinking of a discrete rv that takes on only one value in some alphabet or a continuous rv that has as its pdf the Dirac delta function. Just any rv that can take only one value in its alphabet.

Comment: The answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156404/entropy-of-a-uniform-distribution should answer your questions.

Comment: Even when the distribution is that of a constant, you still need to specify which value it takes on.  But trying to compare this *differential entropy* with the discrete entropy is problematic: the interpretations do not directly translate from one to the other.

Comment: For negative differential entropy see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73881/when-is-the-differential-entropy-negative